# How to translate arithmetic expression from SQL to JPQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, jpql

I have a database where I made a query successfully in SQL, but the matter is that I need to write this same query in JPQL for a method of one REST service.

This is the query that worked:

```
SELECT * FROM user u WHERE SQRT(POW(69.1 * (u.latitude - 38.0),2) + POW(69.1 * (-2.8 - u.longitude) * COS(u.latitude / 57.3), 2)) < 100
```

I need to change the values written there as "38.0" and "-2.8" and "100" to input parameters and make it in JPQL.

This is what I tried

```
@GET
@Path("nearusers={lat}&{lon}&{dist}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public List<Usuario> findNearUsers(@PathParam("lat") BigDecimal lat,@PathParam("lon") BigDecimal lon, @PathParam("dist") BigDecimal dist){

    TypedQuery query = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE SQRT(POW(69.1 * (u.latitude - :lat),2) + POW(69.1 * (:lon - u.longitude) * COS(u.latitude / 57.3), 2)) < :dist",Usuario.class);

    List<User> users = query
            .setParameter("lat", lat)
            .setParameter("lon", lon)
            .setParameter("dist", dist)
            .getResultList();
    return users;
}
```

And when I launch this service method what I'm getting by my server is an error that says:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE SQRT(POW(69.1 * (u.latitud - :lat),2) + POW(69.1 * (:lon - u.longitud) * COS(u.latitud / 57.3), 2)) < :dist]. 
[35, 129] The encapsulated expression is not a valid expression
```

The IDE (Netbeans) is showing some warnings in the line I forming the query:
[IDE warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDcsS.png)

I tried to change the expression several times, adding brackets, casting parameters to double, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`POW` and `COS` are not supported by JPQL**. In addition to basic arithmetic operations, JPQL only supports a limited set of arithmetic operations: `ABS`, `SQRT`, `MOD`, `SIZE`, `INDEX` (see [JPA 2.1 Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html), Sec. 4.6.17.2.2).

Therefore, you need to use a **JPA native query** formulated in the SQL dialect of your database:

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(
     "SELECT * FROM user u WHERE SQRT(POW(69.1 * (u.latitude - ?1),2) + POW(69.1 * (?2 - u.longitude) * COS(u.latitude / 57.3), 2)) < ?3", 
     User.class);

List<User> users = query
  .setParameter(1, lat)
  .setParameter(2, lon)
  .setParameter(3, dist)
  .getResultList();
```

Notice that a native query is still capable of returning managed entities.

Comment: I marked immediately when I ckecked that worked but stackoverlows says that I dont have enough reputation to mark as correct  because im a new user, and that they only can record my vote but not show it.
Sorry for that buddy. Anyway thank you again for the help !

Edit: Sorry was a mistake, the matter was I was trying to vote instead of mark as accepted, sorry for that it was my first post.